# Plot one dimensional bloch wave function

Tags: python, arrays, function, python-3.x

I'm new to both quantum physics and coding, so I would appreciate some help on my code. I'm trying to plot a Bloch wave function in one dimension with c-constants as `c(-1)=0.5, c(0)=1 and c(1)=0.5`, and I define the c-values as an array. But I'm not sure that this is the best way to do it. The Bloch wave function shall go through x-values of `0-10 (Å)`.

I code in Python. I have trouble with understanding how to code that i want my function to go trough `c(-1)=0.5, c(0)=1, c(1)=0.5 for every point in x=[0,10]`.

I would really appreciate some feedback on my code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import peplos as pl
from matplotlib import animation
import math 

#Define constants 
N=1 
n=1
a=2
L=N*n*a
k=( 2 * math.pi ) / L
G = ( 2 * math.pi * n ) / a
x = np.array([ 0 , 10 ])

#Defining the c-values 
c = np.array([0.5,1,0.5])

#Defining the function 
def psi(x):
    return c*(np.exp((1j*(k+G)*x)))

for x in range: 
    for c in range: 
        y=psi(x) 

pl.plot(x,y) 
pl.show()
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please add the name of the language you're using. Why isn't your code doing what you expect, what is your actual question?

Comment: Thanks. Im coding in Python. I have trouble with understanding how to code that i want my function to go trough c(-1)=0.5, c(0)=1, c(1)=0.5 for every point in x=[0,10].

Comment: You're using `c=0.5` twice, is that on purpose?